# Parse Large Excel file on with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to parse large excel file with any javascript library to get worksheet names to allow user to choose worksheets that will be process on the server side.
I see this library https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls can parse excel file but will load all the file into memory and the client machine will freeze if file is too large. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

#### ExcelJS

Read, manipulate and write spreadsheet data and styles to XLSX and JSON. I haven't tested this myself, but the api looks extensive with a lot of possibilities.

*[exceljs project page](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs)*

Code example:

```
// read from a file
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
    .then(function() {
        // use workbook
    });

// pipe from stream
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());
```

Comment: Thank You. I have a look to exceljs before I asked the question . Are you think it will work on the client side ? it's depend on many Node.js libraries

Comment: I dont think this would work client side. You can use this client side library for handling a stream from a csv file http://papaparse.com/ A stream means you dont have to put the whole thing in memory just read it chunk by chunk. And then use this client side library to convert excel to csv file https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-js

Comment: I want to parse xls , xlsx files and I see papaparse handle the plain-text files based on separator CSV , PSV, TSV ,... but XLS , XLSX is a zipped files. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ya which is why you would want to convert it to CSV with library i mentioned, simple-excel-js

Comment: OK , I will try it. Thank you

Comment: This library https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-js not implemented xls and xlsx I will create my own library to load global data (sheet names) without load the sheets data and will share it here. Thanks for your time.